# AttributeError: 'EntitySet' object has no attribute 'plot' in featuretools

Tags: python-3.x, featuretools

I am getting this exception when I try to run the command:

```
es.plot()

AttributeError: 'EntitySet' object has no attribute 'plot'
```

The es object is an 'EntitySet' class object in featuretools.

I created es using the following commands:

```
es = es.entity_from_dataframe(entity_id = 'orders',
                             dataframe = orders,
                             index = 'order_id',
                             variable_types = {

                                 'user_id' : ft.variable_types.Categorical,

                                 'eval_set' : ft.variable_types.Categorical,

                                 'order_number' : ft.variable_types.Numeric,

                                 'order_dow' : ft.variable_types.Numeric,

                                 'order_hour_of_day' : ft.variable_types.Numeric,

                                 'days_since_prior_order' : ft.variable_types.Numeric
                             })

es = es.entity_from_dataframe(entity_id = 'products',
                             dataframe = products,
                             index = 'product_id',
                             variable_types = {

                                 'product_name' : ft.variable_types.Categorical,

                                 'aisle_id' : ft.variable_types.Categorical,

                                 'department_id' : ft.variable_types.Categorical
                             })

es = es.entity_from_dataframe(entity_id = 'departments',
                             dataframe = departments,
                             index = 'department_id',
                             variable_types = {

                                 'department' : ft.variable_types.Categorical
                             })

es = es.entity_from_dataframe(entity_id = 'aisles',
                             dataframe = aisles,
                             index = 'aisle_id',
                             variable_types = {

                                 'aisle' : ft.variable_types.Categorical
                             })
```

The data can be obtained here: https://www.instacart.com/datasets/grocery-shopping-2017

I am trying to follow the Featuretools tutorial named: **Predicting a customer's next purchase using automated feature engineering**

For more information on Featuretools look here: https://docs.featuretools.com/index.html

Answer (score 1):

`EntitySet.plot()` was added in Featuretools v0.6.0. Make sure you are on the most recent Featuretools version. You can install it with pip by running the following command

```
pip install --upgrade featuretools
```